# Microphone on Dell xps 13 9343

Tags: 14.04, sound, dell, microphone

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my xps 13 (non touchscreen). The current kernal is 3.16.0-49, and bios is version A05. I have wifi and the trackpad working, but the mic no longer does. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dell XPS 9343 microphone is currently broken on kernel 3.16.

---

You have to use kernel 3.19 which contains a fix for the microphone.

There are two ways to do it :

1. Manually install kernel 3.19 on your current Ubuntu installation.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid linux-image-generic-lts-vivid
   ```
2. Upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 (which has kernel 3.19).
   I wrote a [full guide](http://hgdev.co/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-the-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide-update/) on how to do it on this laptop.

Comment: Oh, it's you, your guide was wonderful and it's the only reason I have wifi on it.

Comment: Glad it helped =)

Answer (score 1):

Something that worked for me (on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-87) was to install `pavucontrol` and set it as the 'fallback' on the input devices tab. It seems that the default audio settings controller in Ubuntu 16.04 wasn't picking up the internal mic properly, but `pavucontrol` spotted it fine (the levels were jumping when I made noise), and I just needed to set it as the default (fallback?).I got the idea from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9343)#Audio) even though I am not using archlinux.